# Avoiding Robots from registering on your site

Tags: validation, drupal, captcha

I'm in the process of setting up a basic site for cell phone reviews and information. I keep getting these fake accounts registering and posting content on my site that is not appropriate.

I have just installed the CAPTCHA and image CAPTCHA module, but this doesn't seem to be stopping them.

What is the best way to avoid these fake accounts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another strategy is to add another field in the user registration form.  Most bots wouldn't know which fields are required, so they fill in everything.  If the user enters a value into the new field then don't create an account.  You can hide the field from the UI with CSS so that real people won't be able to see the field and enter anything into it.  Read [Easy spam prevention using hidden forms](http://www.sitepoint.com/easy-spam-prevention-using-hidden-form-fields/) for a detailed explanation.

To implement this feature into your Drupal site, you need to create a module to alter the user registration form and create a validation for it.

Add another field to the user registration form:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['field_fname'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Answer if you are a bot',
      '#type' => 'textfield',
    );
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_user_bot_validate';
  }
}
```

Add the validation:

```
function mymodule_user_bot_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if($form['field_fname']['#value'] != '') {
    form_set_error('bot_prevention', t('Could not create your account.'));
    drupal_goto('user/register');
  }
}
```

Then hide the field with CSS.

Comment: There's a module called [Profile 2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2), but it only adds other fields to the form.  You still need to do the validation yourself so I still recommend creating the custom module.  The code I provided is pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you.       6748485468